# How do I convert Oracle internal date to Excel date in Excel?

Tags: oracle, excel

I have a .csv file which was captured from an Oracle database. The date in the .csv file is in the Oracle internal format (not sure what it's called as I'm not familiar with Oracle). It looks like `16474`

When I look at that date in the app we use to access the DB, the date is `2/6/2013`.

However, when I import the .csv file into Excel and format the column as Short Date, it shows the date as `2/6/1945`

I did a random sampling, and it looks like the month/day is always correct, but the year is off by 68 years. I'm assuming this is because Oracle's "beginning of time" is different than Excel's "beginning of time"

Any way to fix this so the dates show properly when importing the Oracle data into Excel?

I don't have access to anything on the Oracle side .. just the .csv file, and Excel. I'm also ultimately importing the Excel file into Access if that helps.

So far, I formatted the Oracle date as Short Date in Excel, and inserted a column next to my date column (J) and used the following:

```
=DATE(YEAR(J1)+68,MONTH(J1),DAY(J1))
```

I'm not sure if that is 100% accurate considering leap years

EDIT: I think this code may do it:

```
Public Sub ReplaceData()

    Dim RangeCell As Range

    For Each RangeCell In Selection

        If IsNumeric(RangeCell.Value) Then
            lngDate = CLng(RangeCell.Value)
            RangeCell.Value = DateAdd("d", lngDate - 1, "1/1/1968")
        End If

    Next RangeCell

End Sub
```

Comment: `csv` is not an Oracle format. Furthermore, the `Date` datatype has no format in Oracle: `date` are converted to whatever format the client asks when it need to be displayed/saved to a file. Since you can't update the export process, this is a 100% Excel question :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - The data is captured by the 'capture' feature in the AccuTerm software that accesses the Oracle db. To get it, I run 2 commands: `SELECT TABLENAME` and then `LIST.TAB FIELD1 FIELD2` .. is there anything I can do during that process to convert `FIELD2` from `16474` to `2/6/2013`?

Comment: I don't know this tool, can you add a function to your column? Using [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129) is the standard function to specify a `date` format in Oracle. Alternatively you could query a view which contains the `to_char` conversion.

Comment: thanks Vincent .. I will look into that. I'm not too familiar with the tool either :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Oracle may begin on 1/1/1968. I'm not a DB guy but I think that number sounds familiar in other reading I have done.

Here is an example routine that would convert the Oracle date to Excel date, if the above assumption of 1/1/1968 is true.

```
Sub OracleToExcelCSVDates()
Dim rng as Range 'range of cells containing dates'
Dim cl as Range
Dim strDate As String 'date received from Oracle'
Dim lngDate As Long
Dim newDate As Date 'Converted date'

Set rng = Range("J1:J1000") '< modify this for the number of rows you use in col J'

For each cl in rng 'Iterate over the rng you defined above.'
    'Capture the date from Oracle'
    strDate = cl.Value
    If Not Trim(strDate) = vbNullString Then 'ignore blanks'
        'convert to Long data type'
        lngDate = CLng(strDate)

        'Add the # of days (lngDate) to Oracles base date of 1/1/1968'
        newDate = DateAdd("d", lngDate - 1, "1/1/1968")

        'Overwrite the cell value with the new converted date:'
        cl.Value = newDate
    End If

End Sub
```

**More info about Excel dates:**

Excel stores serial dates as "a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:   ddddd.tttttt . This is called a serial date, or serial date-time."

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.

Comment: Nope, I'm not sure. Just going from OP's assumption of 1/1/1968. If it's 1/1/1970 (or any other date, for that matter), just change the last argument in the `DateAdd` function to correspond with the correct base date.

Comment: Thanks David .. assuming the date in Excel is column J, can you please show me what your code would look like to convert any value in column J?

Comment: Disregard that .. I think I was able to do it